# How to get all transaction logs for a specific program? Both old and new transactions

Tags: geyser, logs

What is the best way to get all the program logs from a specific program?

There are two types of logs I am curious about getting for any given programId:

- all the older, already finalized, transaction logs from a specific program
- monitoring the program and getting all the inflight transaction logs as the transactions are getting processed

I would assume for the second, running a geyser plugin would be the way? But is there an efficient way to get older transaction logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How do I monitor a program and get inflight transaction logs?

The absolute best way is hooking up a geyser plugin and filtering based on your program.

A less infra-heavy way would be to use the RPC websocket [logSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#logssubscribe), but this is slightly less reliable.

Relying on a third party service, some indexers on Solana provide [webhooks](https://docs.helius.xyz/webhooks/webhooks-api-reference/create-webhook) you can use to get program logs + other information

2. How do I get all the older, already finalized, transaction logs from a specific program?

If you have a BigTable instance storing transaction data, you can get the logs from that. You would have to take snapshots and load old data in order to get the log.

**Note**: [Early blocks of Mainnet-beta will not have log data](https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/916393201772929065/1087779139215441961) because long-term storage of log metadata was not implemented at that time

Comment: Can you load a BigTable instance from any snapshot? Or do you have to start from the beginning and work back (or vice versa)?

Comment: iirc snapshots contain large amounts of blocks you can then load to keep track of the ledger https://docs.solana.com/validator/best-practices/operations#snapshots